# I can't access the keys of checkbox with javascript when I generate the checkbox dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I created a checkbox in my html.erb as the following:

```
<%= check_box_tag(:fenix_fee_charged) %>
<%= label_tag(:fenix_fee_charged, "FENIX_FEE_CHARGED") %>
<%= check_box_tag(:fenix_fee_no_charged) %>
<%= label_tag(:fenix_fee_no_charged, "FENIX_FEE_NO_CHARGED") %>
```

I created the javascript to set one or another:

```
$('#fenix_fee_charged').click(function(){
    $('#fenix_fee_no_charged').removeAttr("checked");
});
$('#fenix_fee_no_charged').click(function(){
    $('#fenix_fee_charged').removeAttr("checked");
});
```

When my options to check increased, I decided to create the checkbox dynamically:

```
<% Enums::FlightEnum::FENIX_FLIGHTS_NOTIFICATIONS.each do |notification, value| %>
  <%= check_box_tag notification, value %>
  <%= label_tag notification, notification.to_s.upcase, :class => "checkbox inline" %>
<% end %>
```

When I checked the javascript function, this did not work. I would appreciate any help that you can give me!

Comment: Use [event delegation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414695/attaching-events-after-dom-manipulation-using-jquery-ajax).

Comment: Is there any js error. try to print something using 'console.log' in click function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the checkbox are added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$(document).on('click', '#fenix_fee_charged', function(event) {
    $('#fenix_fee_no_charged').removeAttr("checked"); 
});

$(document).on('click', '#fenix_fee_no_charged', function(event) {
    $('#fenix_fee_charged').removeAttr("checked"); 
});
```

**EDIT**

Also try to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method like:

```
// Uncheck the checkbox
$('#fenix_fee_no_charged').prop("checked", false);

// Check the checkbox
$('#fenix_fee_no_charged').prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Of course he's using jQuery 1.6 or above -- you just told him to use `.on` which requries jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 2):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use Event Delegation.

```
$(document).on('click', '#fenix_fee_charged', function(event) {
    $('#fenix_fee_no_charged').removeAttr("checked"); 
})
```