# Click event not working on data that is added to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on an image I run a method:

```
$('#file-list li img').on('click', this.beeClick);
```

Later on, I add more images, to the list but the event fails to work. How can I apply this so that any new images also can be clicked on?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414695/attaching-events-after-dom-manipulation-using-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use event delegation.  Try this:

```
$('#file-list li').on('click', 'img', this.beeClick);
```

If you are dynamically adding an 'li' tag and an 'img' tag (not just an 'img' tag) to the already created element with an id of 'file-list' then you would need to change it to:

```
$('#file-list').on('click', 'img', this.beeClick);
```

Comment: @panthro, are you dynamically adding the 'img' tag and the 'li' tag or just the 'img' tag?

Comment: I clone a li template on the page and then add the img tag to that clone.

Comment: @panthro, I updated my example.  Take a look at the second code snippet, you would need to use that.