# jQuery on blur not working properly

Tags: jquery, validation, dynamic, blur

I have a simple educational details page where I am generating textboxes dynamically to enter qualification details. When I try to validate the textboxes, the validation gets fired but not properly. If I try it 2-3 times then it becomes proper. In the first attempt alternate textboxes get validated. When I click on "add row" button a new row gets added but when I try to validate it for 2-3 attempts the validation error is not shown. After few more attempts the validation works. It is all very confusing.

I researched a lot on the internet but could not find any proper solution.

I have pasted my full JSP below. Will be really really thankful for any pointers.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Enter Details</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.validate.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />

        <script src="../js/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.validation.functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">       
       $(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery(".validate-text").on("blur", function (event) {
           setTimeout(function() {
               jQuery(".validate-text").validate({
            expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
            message: "Please enter value."
            }); });
    });
       jQuery(".validate-num").on("blur", function (event) {
           setTimeout(function() {
               jQuery(".validate-num").validate({
            expression: "if (!isNaN(VAL) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
            message: "Please enter value."
            });
           });
    });
       });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

         $("#addRow").click(function() {
            var i=0;
            i= $("#countHd").val();
            i= parseInt($("#countHd").val(),10); 
             $("table").append('<tr>'+
                    '<td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" class="validate-text" name="courseTxt'+i+'" id="courseTxt'+i+'" /></td>'+
                    '<td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" class="validate-text" name="boardTxt'+i+'" id="boardTxt'+i+'" /></td>'+
                    '<td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" class="validate-num"  style="width: 80px;" name="marksTxt'+i+'" id="marksTxt'+i+'" /></td>'+
                    '<td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" class="validate-num"  style="width: 80px;" name="totalTxt'+i+'" id="totalTxt'+i+'"  /></td>'+
                    '<td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" style="width: 80px;" name="percentageTxt'+i+'" id="percentageTxt'+i+'" style="width: 80px;"  /></td>'+
                    '<td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" class="validate-text"  style="width: 80px;" name="classTxt'+i+'" id="classTxt'+i+'"  /></td>'+
                '</tr>');
             i=i+1;
             $("#countHd").val(i); 
            });
        });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="contain">

<div id="header">
<h3>Enter Details</h3>
</div>

<form id="personalDetails" class="MasterForm" method="post"
    action="AddPersonalDetails.php">
<table class="MasterTable">
    <tr><td class="MasterTabletd">
    <input type="button" name="addRow" id="addRow" class="submitbutton" value="Add Row" /></td>
    <td class="MasterTabletd">
    <input type="submit" name="educational" id="educational" class="submitbutton" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Course Name<span class="required">*</span></td>
    <td>Board / University<span class="required">*</span></td>
    <td>Marks Obtained<span class="required">*</span></td>
    <td>Total Marks<span class="required">*</span></td>
    <td>Percentage<span class="required">*</span></td>
    <td>Year of Completion<span class="required">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" name="courseTxt" id="courseTxt" class="validate-text" /></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" name="boardTxt" id="boardTxt" class="validate-text" /></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" name="marksTxt" id="marksTxt" class="validate-num" /></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" name="totalTxt" id="totalTxt" class="validate-num" /></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" name="percentageTxt" id="percentageTxt" /></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" name="classTxt" id="classTxt" class="validate-text"  /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="countHd" id="countHd" value="1" />
</form>
</div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're creating those elements dynamically, try [delegating your events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679432/jquery-event-delegation):

```
jQuery(document).on("blur",".validate-text", function (event) { 
// repeat for ".validate-num"
```

Additionally, you shouldn't be using two different versions of jQuery. Remove `<script src="../js/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `blur` .. have you tried using `focusout`

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
$(document).ready(function(){

   jQuery("body").on("focusout", ".validate-text", function (event) {
       setTimeout(function() {
           jQuery(".validate-text").validate({
              expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
              message: "Please enter value."
           }); 
       });
   });
   jQuery("body").on("focusout", ".validate-num", function (event) {
       setTimeout(function() {
           jQuery(".validate-num").validate({
              expression: "if (!isNaN(VAL) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
              message: "Please enter value."
           });
       });
    });

});
</script>
```

Read more about `focusout` here:

http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

major difference between [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) and blur is that [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) support event bubbling.

> The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses focus. This is distinct from the blur event in that it supports detecting the loss of focus on descendant elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).

it is often used with [focusin](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/)

an codepen or jsfiddle example would be helpful also