# Dynamic field validation miss fires

Tags: jquery, jsp, validation

I have a jsp page which has two tabs, each having a separate form. In the second tab form, I am generating dynamic rows with textboxes. I have added validation by applying classes on the text fields. The code validation is firing for dynamic fields but when I enter correct values, the validation error message does not clear.

The code is pasted below

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/simpletabs.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.validate.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validation.functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/simpletabs_1.3.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
           .adHeadline {font: bold 10pt Arial; text-decoration: underline; color: #003366;}
           .adText {font: normal 10pt Arial; text-decoration: none; color: #000000;}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">       
       $(document).ready(function(){
           jQuery(document).on("blur",".validate-text", function (event) {
             jQuery(".validate-text").validate({
            expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
            message: "Only characters allowed."
            });
        });
           jQuery(document).on("blur",".validate-num", function (event) {
               jQuery(".validate-num").validate({
            expression: "if (!isNaN(VAL) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
            message: "Only numbers allowed."
            });
    });
           jQuery("#genderRad").validate({
               expression: "if (isChecked(SelfID)) return true; else return false;",
               message: "Select one option."
           });

           jQuery("#emailTxt").validate({
               expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[^\\W][a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+([a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+)*\\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)) return true; else return false;",
               message: "Enter a valid email-id."
           });
       });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

         $("#addRow").click(function() {
            var i=0;
            i= $("#countHd").val();
            i= parseInt($("#countHd").val(),10); 
             $("table").append('<tr>'+
                    '<td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" class="validate-text" name="courseTxt'+i+'" id="courseTxt'+i+'" /></td>'+
                    '<td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" class="validate-text" name="boardTxt'+i+'" id="boardTxt'+i+'" /></td>'+
                    '<td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" class="validate-num" name="marksTxt'+i+'" id="marksTxt'+i+'" /></td>'+
                    '<td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" class="validate-num" name="totalTxt'+i+'" id="totalTxt'+i+'"  /></td>'+
                    '<td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" name="percentageTxt'+i+'" id="percentageTxt'+i+'" /></td>'+
                    '<td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" class="validate-num" name="classTxt'+i+'" id="classTxt'+i+'"  /></td>'+
                '</tr>');
             i=i+1;
             $("#countHd").val(i); 
            });
        });


        </script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="contain">

<div id="header">
<h3>Enter Details</h3>
</div>

<div class="simpleTabs">
                <ul class="simpleTabsNavigation" id="tab1">
                    <li><a href="#">Personal Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Educational Details</a></li>  
                </ul>
                <div class="simpleTabsContent">

                <form id="personalDetails" class="MasterForm" method="post" action="InsertData?add=personal">

    <p>${message}</p>
    <%
        session.setAttribute("message","");
    %>
<table class="MasterTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><label class="MasterLabel">First Name
        :<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text"  class="validate-text" 
            name="fNameTxt" id="fNameTxt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><label class="MasterLabel">Last Name
        :<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text"   class="validate-text" 
            name="lNameTxt" id="lNameTxt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><label class="MasterLabel">Age
        :<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text"  class="validate-num"  
            name="ageTxt" id="ageTxt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><label class="MasterLabel">Gender
        :<span class="required">*</span></label></td> 
        <td class="MasterTabletd">
        <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="genderRad" id="genderRad_M" value="M" />Male
        <input type="radio" name="genderRad" id="genderRad_F" value="F" />Female
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><label class="MasterLabel">Mobile No
        :<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" class="validate-num"  
            name="mobileNoTxt" id="mobileNoTxt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><label class="MasterLabel">Email
        :<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" 
            name="emailTxt" id="emailTxt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="MasterTabletd" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" name="personal" id="personal" class="submitbutton" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form> </div>
                <div class="simpleTabsContent"  id="tab2">

                <form id="educationalDetails" class="MasterForm" method="post"
    action="AddPersonalDetails.php">
<table class="MasterTable">
    <tr><td class="MasterTabletd" colspan="6" style="text-align: left;">
    <input type="button" name="addRow" id="addRow" class="submitbutton"  value="Add Row" /></td>
    <td class="MasterTabletd">
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Course Name<span class="required">*</span></td>
    <td>Board / University<span class="required">*</span></td>
    <td>Marks Obtained<span class="required">*</span></td>
    <td>Total Marks<span class="required">*</span></td>
    <td>Percentage<span class="required">*</span></td>
    <td>Year of Completion<span class="required">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" name="courseTxt" id="courseTxt" class="validate-text" /></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" name="boardTxt" id="boardTxt" class="validate-text" /></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" name="marksTxt" id="marksTxt" class="validate-num" /></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" name="totalTxt" id="totalTxt" class="validate-num" /></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" name="percentageTxt" id="percentageTxt" /></td>
        <td class="MasterTabletd"><input type="text" name="classTxt" id="classTxt" class="validate-num"  /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="educational" id="educational" class="submitbutton" value="Submit" /></td>
    <br></br>
<input type="hidden" name="countHd" id="countHd" value="1" />
</form>

                </div>
            </div>
    </div>          

         </body>
</html>
```

This approach was suggesting is my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302073/jquery-on-blur-not-working-poperly)

Also while testing the validation on second page validation on the first page gets fired. How to avoid this? Is there any better method to implement the same?

Will be thankful to any help.

Thanks in advance.