# .hover event not working for elements loaded dynamically after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following event handler for a set of `div`s which are loaded dynamically through jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.one span').hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#666666', color: '#DDDDDD', marginRight: 5 }, 250);
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD', color: '#666666', marginRight: 0 }, 250);
    });
});
```

The issue is these event handlers are not getting fired and I suspect it's probably because these elements `$('.one span')` are loaded through jQuery after the page is loaded.

What can I do in this situation? How can I do some kind of "late-binding" for elements which will come later?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679432/jquery-event-delegation

Comment: Are you loading `.one` and `span` or just `span`? If you are loading both, what is the parent of `.one`? The answers are related to event delegation ^^.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$('.one span').hover(` use a delegated event since it is dynamically added to DOM. See below,

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.one span', function () {
  $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#666666', color: '#DDDDDD', marginRight: 5 }, 250);
}).on('mouseleave', '.one span', function () {
   $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD', color: '#666666', marginRight: 0 }, 250);
});
```

Replace `document` with closest container that exist when executing the above script.

Comment: [`.on` doesn't work with `hover`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes). You need `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` separately.  http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Za7Y3/

Comment: @Blazemonger Thanks. Updated, had it as `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` but thought i saw `.hover` somewhere and changed it.. but was verifying that in API docs.