# show div only for first category on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

I have applied some jquery on my navigation bar in which navigation items are dynamically generated through mysql database. It opens the div for the first category but does not open it for another one's. In the div there are sub menus.

**Nav**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">CATEGORIES</a></li>
           <?php
                $res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM category");
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    ?>
           <li id="li_toggle">
            <a href="#" ><?php echo $row['cat_name'] ?></a>
            <div id="nav_toggle" style="display: none">
        <ul>
             <?php
         $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE cat_id=".$row['cat_id']);
         while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {
         ?>
        <li>
        <a href="index.php?page=items&category=<?php echo $row1['s_cat_name'] ?>&s_cat_id=<?php echo $row1['s_cat_id'] ?>&cat_id=<?php echo $row1['cat_id'] ?>">
          <?php echo $row1['s_cat_name'] ?>
        </a>
        </li>

       <?php
        }
       ?>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <?php
       }
      ?>
     </ul>
     </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#li_toggle").mouseenter(function (e) {
            $('#nav_toggle').show("slide", {
                direction: "right"
            }, 2000);
            $('.p123h').css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "z-index": "1"
            });
        });
        $("#li_toggle").mouseout(function (e) {
            $('#nav_toggle').hide("slide", {
                direction: "left"
            }, 2000);
            $('.p123h').css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "z-index": "-1"
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef you are pointing `li_toggle` id or `nav_toggle`

Comment: you can see my answer below .. and check the part of ('body').on('mouseenter')

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Thanks! it helped me some how But the answer by Dan solved the issue.

Comment: you solved the issue .. that's it .. Very good Luck :)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ids must be unique for jquery to get get them, Or change them to a class and the the jquery will be applied to each element.

Change nav_toggle to a class and then use $(".nav_toggle") instead the li will also need to be changed to a class

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** as I said .. Id must be unique .. don't use same Id for more than one element .. use classes instead

... While you use loop it will print same id for more than one element so again use `class=""`  instead of `id=""`

**2nd:** for getting first category you have 2 ways

.. you can use :first selector

```
$('.categoryClass:first > div')
```

or you can use .first()

```
$('.categoryClass').first().find('> div')
```

and while you use while loop to dynamically generated elements you will need to use

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.categoryClass' , function(){
   //code here
});
```

you can take a look at [jQuery event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679432/jquery-event-delegation)

> Note: before anything please be sure to include jquery