# How to delete a row based on its index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to delete a selected row using jQuery. First, while clicking add button, rows are added dynamically with a delete button. Now I want to delete the selected row.

I am using the following code to add rows dynamically:

```js
$("#btnAdd").on('click', function (){  
  $('#Time tr').last().after('<tr><td><span style="font-size:14px;">Diplamo/Certificate :</span><input type="textbox" input id="addedValue12" name = "Certificate"></td><td><span style="font-size:14px;">Percentage :</span><input type="textbox" id="addedValue123" name = "CertificatePer"></td></tr>');   
});
```

```html
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="add" />
<table id="Time"> 
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am displaying values in a JSP page.

```html
<c:forEach var="var1" items="${empedu.empCertificate}">
  Certificate Name:<input value="${var1.certification}" name="Certificate" type="text" title="Only Text Allowed" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s'.,@:&?!()$#/\\]+" />
  Percentage: <input value="${var1.percentage}" name="CertificatePer" style="width: 100px;" type="text" max="100" />
  <input type="button" id="deleteRow" name="delete" value="delete" /><br/>
</c:forEach>
```

It is displayed on screen like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Here, If I click the third row, I want to delete the third row. How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at the [`jQuery.remove`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#Time").on("click", ".delete", function(){

    $(this).closest("tr").remove();

});
```

Assuming `delete` is the class of the delete `button`. I have used `.on` as the rows and thus delete buttons are dynamically added.

This is picking the closest `tr` from the clicked delete button, and removing it.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9umGT/72/)

Comment: Thanku so much. But I dont know why it is not working. Please look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9umGT/71/

Comment: @sathishkumar id should be `Time` and not `time`. Look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9umGT/72/

Comment: If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as right answer.

Comment: @sathishkumar please mark this as the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

**1st:** Id must be unique so don't use id for more than one element .. use class instead

**2nd:** while you append rows you need to [jQuery event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679432/jquery-event-delegation)  ...

```
$('#Time').on('click' , '.delete' , function(){  
    // change .delete_btn with your delete btn class
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: I removed id and now my class name delete. Instead of $("#time") if I give $("body") , alert is printing and its coming inside this function. But row is not deleted.

Comment: @sathishkumar after you change class to delete .. see updated answer .. just I changed the .delete_btn  with your new btn class  delete .. even you change $("#time")  with $("body") it should work

Comment: @sathishkumar yes just uppercase the first letter .. Good Luck :)