# change order of elements after click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wont to change order of paragraphs(the one clicked by user should be at the top). I came up with this:

```
<div>
<p>11111111</p>
<p>22222222</p>
<p>33333333</p>
</div>

$("p").click(function(){
  var a = $(this).index();
  if (a != 0) {
   $(this).clone().prependTo("div");
   $(this).remove();
  }
})
```

but it works just "once".

http://plnkr.co/edit/6VlWbIlGi7fDBv6d0WT2?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not very far off, it's actually easier than that: Just prepend the element to its own parent with [`prependTo`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo):

```js
$("p").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prependTo($this.parent());
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p>11111111</p>
  <p>22222222</p>
  <p>33333333</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want, you don't even really need jQuery for it:

```js
$("p").click(function() {
  this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this.parentNode.firstChild);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p>11111111</p>
  <p>22222222</p>
  <p>33333333</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: or even simpler `$(this).parent().prepend(this)`

Comment: @charlietfl: Not sure that's any simpler, but sure. It's one line less. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.insertBefore();` and you need to [jQuery event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679432/jquery-event-delegation) as well

```js
$("div").on('click','p:not(:nth-child(1))',function(){
  $(this).insertBefore('p:nth-child(1)');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>11111111</p>
<p>22222222</p>
<p>33333333</p>
</div>
```