# Loading content with AJAX/jquery, and still be able to use other javascript functions on the generated DOM

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have made a table which is dynamicly created using PHP.

It basicly looks like this.

```
<table class="persist-area table table-bordered ">
    <thead>
        <tr class="persist-header">
          <th>1. th</th>
          <th>2. th</th>
          <th>3. th</th>
          <th>4. th</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="maintable">         
  <span class="genTable" id="<?php echo $partnerId ?>">
  </thead>
      <tbody class="maintable">         
      <span class="genTable" id="<?php echo $partnerId ?>">';

     <?php echo  $partner->genTable();?>

     </span>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have this directly in my `partner.php` file.

Now, I want to create an `AJAX` function, that loads this table when you visit partner.php and so that I am able to call the function, everytime the user makes changes to the table.

So I created this javascript function:

```
function  genTable(){
  $.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url: "resources/dialogs/genTable.php",
            data: {'partnerId': '1'},
        success: function(msg){
           $("div#gentable").html(msg);
        }});
}
```

So this makes a `POST` request to a new file I created, which returns the exact same table as above.

But now my other javascripts does not work on the table anymore.
For instance, I have another script running, to make the table headers persistant on scroll :

```
function UpdateTableHeaders() {

   $(".persist-area").each(function() {

       var el             = $(this),
           offset         = el.offset(),
           scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
           floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

       if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "visible"
           });
       } else {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "hidden"
           });      
       };
   });
}

    // DOM Ready      
    $(function() {
       var clonedHeaderRow;

       $(".persist-area").each(function() {
           clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header", this);
           clonedHeaderRow
             .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
             .css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())
             .addClass("floatingHeader");

       });


       $(window)
        .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
        .trigger("scroll");

    });
```

The code above is just an example. All other javascripts that interact with the table does not work either - is there a way I can make this work?

I'm thinking it has something to do with how the stuff gets loaded? Should I use `livequery` or how to make my other scripts work on the `AJAX` generated content?

As said, all the scripts works fine if I load the table directly from `partner.php` file, but when trying to load it with `AJAX` it breaks.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: When this runs `$(".persist-area").each(function() {` (on DOM ready) it "processes" only existing DOM. After you do the AJAX call and inject your new HTML in the DOM you need to rerun `$(".persist-area").each(function() {` on that new piece of DOM.

Comment: Thanks @SergiuParaschiv - can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery event delegation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679432/jquery-event-delegation)

Comment: Put all of your listeners in your last block of code in a function like listeners(){ // here }; Then call it in your AJAX success block like this: listeners(); Keep in mind that, if the AJAX calls multiple times, you will have multiple listeners. So you would need to remove the old listeners or prevent the duplication with classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually simpler than you think.

All you need to do is put your listener in a function and re-call that function every time your ajax load is complete.