# Jquery apped input on last-child keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am novice to JS and i have to improve my page functionality using Jquery. My current Html is:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">                  
    <div><ul class="inputList"></ul></div>
</div>
```

Goal is to append new input field after last child element every time user press a key in the last input field. But that should happen only once, and after that user can countinue typing without appending new inputs.
And, if user begin typing in that new appended input, another one should be added and so on. I tryed something like this, but that adds field only once.

```
$(".inputList").last().one("keypress",(function () {
  $(wrapper).append('<li><input type="text" name="key" placeholder="Attribute" /><input type="text" name="value" placeholder="Value"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></li>');
}
```

When i remove `one()`, append countinues in every keypress. How should i manage this?

Thanks!

Comment: `. inputList ` is not a input field in your posted code. It is a `UL`.

Comment: Use `on()` instead of `one()` and it should work.

Comment: sure, but i am appending it widh inputst inside <li> elements

Comment: But initially there is no input element to bind the keypress. Can you please provide a fiddle or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can simply remove that `class` from clicked `input` element please find below snippet for more info

```js
$(document).on("keypress",".addanother",function(){
   $(".inputList").append('<li><input type="text" name="key" placeholder="Attribute" /><input type="text" name="value" placeholder="Value" class="addanother"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></li>');
   $(this).removeClass("addanother");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">                  
  <div>
    <ul class="inputList">
    <li>
    <input type="text" name="key" placeholder="Attribute" />
    <input type="text" name="value" placeholder="Value" class="addanother" />
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally for binding event on dynamically created element please find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43587283/2534646)

Answer (score 1):

You must define event handler after append elements.

```js
var appendInput=function(){

 $('<li><input type="text" name="key" placeholder="Attribute" /><input type="text" name="value" ' +
                    'placeholder="Value"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></li>').one("keypress",appendInput).appendTo(".input_fields_wrap");
}

$(".inputList").last().find("input").one("keypress",appendInput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input_fields_wrap">                  
      <div>
      <ul class="inputList"><input type="text"/></ul></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much! I modified a code a little bit and it works perfectly!