# Datables create column header via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

How do i make header title from ajax file?? I'm doing my best like these

```
$('#btntrack').on('click', function() {
            var KPNo = $('#KPNo').val();
            var dataString = 'KPNo='+ $('#KPNo').val();
            //console.log(dataString);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: host+"ajax/tracking/kp",
                data: dataString,
                dataType: 'json',    
                "success": function(json) {
                    var tableHeaders;
                    $.each(json.data[0], function(i, val){
                        tableHeaders += "<th>" + val + "</th>";
                    });

                    $("#tableDiv").empty();
                    $("#tableDiv").append('<table id="tbltrackkp" class="dataTable table table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" cellspacing="0" data-table="kp" width="100%"><thead><tr>' + tableHeaders + '</tr></thead></table>');
```

Well is woking, but when i add these code

```
$('#tbltrackkp').find('tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                        var code = $(this).find('a').attr('id-kp');
                        var modal = $('.bs-modal-lg');
                        var modalData = jQuery.parseJSON(ajaxPOST(code,'ajax/actionkp',null,true));

                        modal.find('.modal-title').html(modalData.title);
                        modal.find('.modal-body').html(modalData.body);
                        modal.find('.modal-footer').html(modalData.footer);

                        modal.modal('show');
                    });
```

Not working at all, i need show modal on each td tbody, but didnt happening, even in network (inpsect element), is didnt get link action. How am i supose to do??

U didnt see my question!! I'm using datatbles and that question not using datatables, is deiffrent dude!!

Update is working now, i'm edit on tag  each td i'm add id="trackingaction", and on jquery i'm change jquery function on tbltrackkp into `$(document).on('click', '#trackingaction', function ()`

Tq for Oluwafemi Sule

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding event to dynamically created elements using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587213/binding-event-to-dynamically-created-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: @Curiousdev, no is not, i'm using just on table, and id form td is diffrent. So it would not duplicated.

Comment: "on tag each td i'm add id="'trackingaction'" doesn't sound right. Ids must be unique. Are you *sure* it's working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `#tbltrackkp` is dynamically inserted in the document, `$('#tbltrackkp').find('tbody').on('click', '...` doesn't register because it doesn't exist at run time.

You can set your listener to the body and only call the handler when it propagates to your selection this way:

```
$('body').on('click', '#tbltrackkp tbody td.details-control', function () { ... }
```

Comment: Well i'm addingt that code but seem not happening, do i need use these code inside button or outside??

Comment: It should be outside inside of _document dot ready_ callback.

Comment: Well is not wokring too, but tahnk to you, i change code insde td on <a> i'm using id="trackingaction", and on jquery i'm using $(document).on('click', '#trackingaction', function () { , and is working perfectly :)